# How to increase spending cap in metamask?

Tags: metamask

I agree to allow 10k coins.

But then latter I want to do 50k transaction.

How would I do so?

Answer (score 0):

Although the question is not very clear. I assume you are talking about the ERC20 approval function.

if you allowed 10k tokens and they are being spent, then you can again allow 50k tokens. Or you can allow a much larger amount, but please explain your question, as this might lead to fund loss.

Comment: A DAPP just fail when I want to spend more than 10k. Disconnecting and reconnecting works. Buggy DAPP